# When can I declare that my language has 'first class X'

Tags: first-class-objects

I don't understand what first class object means, is this word be agreed or strictly defined?

For example, what is `first class function`? As long as the function can assign a value to the variable or pass as a parameter transmission?

If I try to declare my language with `first class effect`, what ability does my language need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formal definition of a first-class citizen is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). Generally, X is first-class if it can be used just like any other object in your language.

For first class effects in particular, you'd need to have effects fully represented as objects. From what limited knowledge I have of the concept of effects, having access to the populated effect container from a handler and being able to perform operations like `resume` on it should probably suffice.

Comment: s/object/value/